# Handsontable Password Renderer

Tags: renderer, handsontable

I tried to apply PasswordRenderer to a specific row and column based on the value of that row.

So my custom renderer looked like this -

```
function firstRowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
Handsontable.renderers.PasswordRenderer.apply(this, arguments); }
```

However the problem I face is, while editing the cells, the field is no longer masked. Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/whxbv6xh/

If you try and edit the first row of that table, the values are not masked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This "unmasking" of the field is what the `PasswordRenderer` is essentially all about. If you want to not be able to see the original values at all you have at least two options:

1.Convert the header row's values beforehand:

```js
function renderAsPassword(password) {
  return new Array(password.length + 1).join('*');
}
alert(['', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda'].map(renderAsPassword));
```

2.Create a custom editor, extending the built-in `PasswordEditor`:

```
var PasswordEditor = Handsontable.editors.PasswordEditor.prototype.extend();

PasswordEditor.prototype.getValue = function() {
    return renderAsPassword(this.TEXTAREA.value);
};

PasswordEditor.prototype.setValue = function(newValue){
    this.TEXTAREA.value = renderAsPassword(newValue);
};
```